# Client script for displaying an alert is not working if I use the AsyncPostBackTrigger

Tags: asp.net

I have a masterpage in my application. I'm using timer control based on the timer interval the page gets refreshed. And I don't want the whole page to get refreshed. So I'm using `AsyncPostBackTrigger` on the tick event of the timer. I want to display an alert/modal dialog box whenever it is triggered. I have written a client script for displaying alert/modal dialog box. The client script is not working if I use the `AsyncPostBackTrigger`. If I remove the trigger, then the whole page is getting refreshed. Is there any way that I can find a solution? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.get_instance();
prm.add_endRequest(function() {
   //put code here
});
```

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Reference.Sys-WebForms-PageRequestManager-endRequest-Event.ashx

Comment: it is not identifiying the "Sys". Do I need to include any AJAX reference or namespace? pls help thanx :)

Comment: Yes, your ASP.NET page needs a ScriptManager reference, and a reference to System.Web.Extensions; this is part of the UpdatePanel requirements, so that should be good...  could you post some of your page markup?